# Convert flat JSON to Parent-Child Hierarchical Structure based on Parent_ID in Java

Tags: java, json, data-structures, parent-child

I have a flat [JSON Structure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a60hkyji0dtql3k/parent-child.json?dl=0) like this, I Want a hierarchical JSON Structure like,

```
{
  "root":{
    "name": "world",
    "children":[
      {
        "name": "Asia",
        "children":[
          {
            "name": "India",
            "children":[
              {
                "name": "WB",
                "...//multiple nested children can be present"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Pakistan",
            "children":[
              "...//multiple nested children can be present"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Europe",
        "children":[
          {
            "name": "Italy",
            "children":[
              {
                "name":"...
                                ...//multiple nested children can be present"
              }
            ]
          },
          "...//multiple nested children can be present"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Like the above structure, there is a scenario where the Root element has no parent ID In the flat JSON structure, and multiple nested children can be present inside every parent.

I have written a code but it doesn't seem to have the exact logic and I can't find the logic, here is the code,

```
package jsonflattener;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.json.JSONArray;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.json.JSONException;

    import org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.json.JSONObject;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    public class JSONMapTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
            JSONArray rootJsonArray = makeJSON();
            Map<String, JSONObject> idNameMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> idNameMap2 = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject idNameMap3 = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < rootJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) rootJsonArray.get(i);
    
                idNameMap.put(data.getString("id"), data);
    
                Set<String> idSet = idNameMap.keySet();
                for (String id : idSet) {
                    JSONObject value = idNameMap.get(id);
                    for (Iterator keys = value.keys(); keys.hasNext(); ) {
                        String key = (String) keys.next();
                        Object pid = value.get("pid");
                        if (pid.equals("")) {
                            idNameMap2.put("root", value.get("name"));
                        } else if (pid.toString().equals(value.getString(id))) {
                            //Insert in this point
                            System.out.println(pid + ":" + key);
                        }
                    }
    
                    Object pid = value.get("pid");
    
    
                }
    
            }
            System.out.println(idNameMap2);
        }
    }
```

In the code, I have taken one id-Name Map and by iterating each parent ID of the map with the key of the id-Name map I can get the JSON Structure. But I am not able to do that because I don't understand where to insert the values exactly.

Please guide me on how I can get the required hierarchical structure using/without using recursion.